# "upowerd[4116]: unhandled action 'bind'" messages filling up syslog

Tags: 18.04, systemd, pci

On a laptop with Ubuntu 18.04, `/var/log/syslog` gets new block of the four following messages about 5 times per second:

```
Aug 29 19:17:17 my_hostname systemd-udevd[336]: Process 'hid2hci --method=dell --devpath=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.2/3-1.2:1.0' failed with exit code 1.
Aug 29 19:17:17 my_hostname upowerd[4116]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.2/3-1.2:1.0
Aug 29 19:17:17 my_hostname systemd-udevd[336]: Process 'hid2hci --method=dell --devpath=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.2/3-1.2:1.0' failed with exit code 1.
Aug 29 19:17:17 my_hostname upowerd[4116]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.2/3-1.2:1.0
```

They are filling up the log partition. I do not have anything plugged in any USB port. The corresponding PCI device is:

```
$ lspci | grep 00:1a.0
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 03)
```

What can be the reason of these messages? How should I correct the situation?

Comment: I am experiencing a very similar error.  Except, I am getting the error when attempting to install 18.04.1.  It is occurring during file system detection and so I can't install it on the system.  Previously, I had 16.4 running just fine on my system.  My best guess is a change to hid2hci between 16 and 18, but I don't know where to begin to look.  Any chance you found a solution?

Comment: Also getting this problem on a dell vostro, with a 1st gen intel i3 chip. Can't find anything else to solve this problem!

Comment: I manually *removed* /var/log/syslog and that immediately stopped the heavy cpu / disk activity. I am now applying all system updates and will report back. But without syslog it seems to be performing OK. I have also installed bcmwl-kernel-source as it was needed for Bluetooth (??) and I saw some reference elsewhere to bluetooth disconnect / reconnect being the issue.

Comment: I would not recommend removing the syslog! That seems dangerous. Do you have a corrupt drive? Have you checked with Disks tool or fsck?

Comment: its an internal USB device within your dell laptop.  maybe a touchscreen ?